# Passing response.data from Ratchet websocket in Vue Instance results in error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this vue instance with `Ratchet` on `mounted()` like this

```
  mounted() {
    this.conn.onopen = function(response) {
      console.log("Connection established!");
    };
  
    this.conn.onmessage = function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.messages.push(response.data);
      console.log(this.messages);
    };
  
  },
```

on top of this I have a variable named messages located on `data:{}` as such

```
data: {
    conn : new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081/'),
    messages: [],
},
```

What I wanted to do is, I want to store said `response.data` from WebSocket conn into messages (`this.messages`) using a simple push, but the console displayed an error like this

```
chatroom.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at WebSocket.conn.onmessage (chatroom.js:32)
conn.onmessage @ chatroom.js:32
```

Can someone enlighten me on why the push into array doesn't work? thanks.

Comment: Working through stackoverflow I found out that during ```conn.onmessage``` the variables arent directly accessible because its an async process, what can I do is create a callback function when data is received, I tried to do so but still on the callback function ```this.messages.push()``` produces error saying ```cannot read property of Push...```

Comment: I haven't used WebSocket, but I do use Vue, and did a little research.  Instead of calling ```new WebSocket(...)``` in ```data```, have you tried calling ```this.conn = new WebSocket(...)``` first thing in ```mounted()```?

Comment: I tried it, but I needed to access `conn` from some method on `method: {}` and I cannot access `conn` using the method if I were to put it on `mounted()` or `created()`

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Since you have defined ```conn``` in ```data```, you can access ```this.conn``` in ```created()```, ```mounted()```, or any function defined in ```method({})```.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, its my lack of understanding about scopes, I found a solution somewhere by doing `let self = this`, this way I can call methods using `self` instead.